# Duplicate symbols error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

My project link to 2 static libraries from 3rd party, one of them requires `-ObjC` flag in linker options. Target build returns the following error:

```
ld: 49 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove `-ObjC` linker flag then the build process will finish successfully. But, by doing that the following exception will be thrown when the app run:

```
2016-01-26 16:05:28.239 testapp[355:167475] -[NSConcreteMutableData SR_stringByBase64Encoding]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14696110
2016-01-26 16:05:28.240 testapp[355:167475] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData SR_stringByBase64Encoding]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14696110'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22c9d68b 0x34486e17 0x22ca2ea5 0x22ca0ad9 0x22bd1258 0xe36e9 0xe6e4d 0x2ead87 0x2f5653 0x2edfe9 0x2f6b35 0x2f698f 0x34d42b45 0x34d42734)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My question is: is there any temporary build option to skip duplicate symbols check? or do I have to inform the library owner to fix their libs?

Comment: What kind of libraries? Can the libraries be managed by Cocoapods?

Comment: @Raptor The libs came from Docomo: https://dev.smt.docomo.ne.jp/?p=index. I have no idea if they can be managed by cocoapods.

Comment: i recommend to use cocoa pod for add your library and manage them!
if you can't please use Obj-C and tell us about about your library , maybe your problem is 1 one of the library include another library

Comment: Sadly Docomo's SDK is not managed via Cocoapods. As mentioned by @MohamadFarhand, one of your library might include part of your another library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-force_load <path/to/lib>` instead of `-ObjC` as linker flag, the project has been built successfully without error.